# How to define and access list in a class - How to access a Player's hand in a Card Game

Tags: c#, list, playing-cards

I realise that this may have been asked before, but I've been looking and while I understand in theory what I need to do, the way to actually make it work is alluding me at the moment.

I'm trying to learn C# and Object Oriented Programming concepts by attempting a project. This particular project is to replicate the Top Trumps Card Game. My theme is going to be Game of Thrones.

My problem is that I'm stumped in regards to populating the Player 1 and computer Hands when I have initialised them. I can see the cards disappearing from the Deck but I cannot see them in the Player's hands (although when I do the breakpoint/pin to source. I can see the cardinHand populate.

The problem is that the game ends up with 60 cards in their hands (in total) instead of 15. ( I 30 rows in an XML that are loaded when the Deck is created).
Can you check my code, give pointers to where I am going wrong. I know that I need to pass the card object around, I fear that I'm just missing something simple. I feel that this is the important part as I want to display the cards in the form based on the players hands.

This is the GameStart Method

```
public static void startGame()
    {
    Player player1 = new Player();
    Player computer = new Player();

    var newdeck = new Deck();
    newdeck.Shuffle();

    while (newdeck.CountCards() != 0)
    {
        newdeck.dealCards();
    }

    MessageBox.Show("New Game Started");
```

This is my Deck Class

```
public class Deck
{

private List<Card> deckofCards = new List<Card>();


//indexer on the deck
// Define the indexer, which will allow client code 
// to use [] notation on the class instance itself. 

public Card this[int i]
{
    get
    {
        // This indexer is very simple, and just returns or sets 
        // the corresponding element from the internal array. 
        return deckofCards[i];
    }
}


public Deck()
{
    resetDeck();
}

public void resetDeck()
{

    XmlDocument xmldata = new XmlDocument();
    xmldata.Load(@"C:\GameofThronesXml.xml");
    XmlNamespaceManager nsmgr = new XmlNamespaceManager(xmldata.NameTable);

    XmlNodeList nodeList;
    XmlElement root = xmldata.DocumentElement;
    nodeList = xmldata.SelectNodes("//CharacterData/record", nsmgr);

    foreach (XmlElement data in nodeList)
    {
        Card singlecard = new Card();
        singlecard.CardID = int.Parse(data.SelectSingleNode("./CardID").InnerText);
        singlecard.Name = data.SelectSingleNode("./Name").InnerText;
        singlecard.Intelligence = int.Parse(data.SelectSingleNode("./Intelligence").InnerText);
        singlecard.Ruthlessness = int.Parse(data.SelectSingleNode("./Ruthlessness").InnerText);
        singlecard.Status = data.SelectSingleNode("./Status").InnerText;
        singlecard.Prestige = int.Parse(data.SelectSingleNode("./Prestige").InnerText);
        singlecard.FightingSkill = int.Parse(data.SelectSingleNode("./FightingSkill").InnerText);
        singlecard.AppearedIn = int.Parse(data.SelectSingleNode("./AppearedIn").InnerText);
        singlecard.Description = data.SelectSingleNode("./Description").InnerText;
        deckofCards.Add(singlecard);
    }

    //string path = @"C:\GameofThronesXml.xml";
    //XElement doc = XElement.Load(path);
    //deckofCards = (from items in doc.Descendants("CharacterData")
    //                select new Card(
    //                        int.Parse(items.Element("CardID").Value),
    //                        items.Element("Picture").Value,
    //                        items.Element("Name").Value,
    //                        int.Parse(items.Element("Intelligence").Value),
    //                        int.Parse(items.Element("Ruthlessness").Value),
    //                        items.Element("Status").Value,
    //                        int.Parse(items.Element("Prestige").Value),
    //                        int.Parse(items.Element("FightingSkill").Value),
    //                        int.Parse(items.Element("AppearedIn").Value),
    //                        items.Element("Description").Value)).ToList();
}

public void Shuffle()
{

    deckofCards = deckofCards.OrderBy(c => Guid.NewGuid())
                 .ToList();

}

public int CountCards()
{

    int number = deckofCards.Count();
    return number;

}

public Card dealCards()
{

    Hand hand = Player.hand;
    //Hand computerHand = Player.hand;

    if (this.deckofCards.Count == 0)
        throw new InvalidOperationException("There are no cards to deal.");

    Card card = deckofCards[0];

    hand.cardsinHand.Add(card);
    deckofCards.RemoveAt(0);
    return card;

 }
}
```

Hand Class

```
public class Hand
  {

    /// <summary>
    /// The deck in the hand
    /// </summary>
    public List<Card> cardsinHand = new List<Card>();

    public int GetNumberofCards()
    {
        int count = cardsinHand.Count;
        return count;
    }

    public void AddCard(Card card)
    {
        cardsinHand.Add(card);
    }



}
```

Player Class

```
public class Player
{

    public static Hand hand = new Hand();


}
```

tl;dr - Want to have two players of Player Class where I can access the number of dealt cards *in this case, 15 cards each* - I know it has something to do with hand.cardsinhand.Count - I just can't access it with the defined player classes.

**Solution** -

```
        Player Player1 = new Player();
        Player Computer = new Player();

        Deck newdeck = new Deck();
        Hand CompHand = new Hand();
        Hand PlyrHand = new Hand();

        newdeck.Shuffle();

        while (newdeck.CountCards() != 0)
        {
            //The Hand adds the return dealt cards to the respective lists.
            CompHand.AddCard(newdeck.dealCards());
            PlyrHand.AddCard(newdeck.dealCards());
        }

        MessageBox.Show("New Game Started");

        //Snoopy Dance - Each card has 15 cards in each hand.
        MessageBox.Show(CompHand.cardsinHand.Count().ToString());
        MessageBox.Show(PlyrHand.cardsinHand.Count().ToString());
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code in `startGame` keeps dealing until there are no cards left:

```
while (newdeck.CountCards() != 0)
{
    newdeck.dealCards();
}
```

But `dealCards` is accessing the static (i.e. shared by all instances of the class) `Player.hand`, so all the cards get added to that. (I guess you were getting 60 when you were adding each card for both players, and that you're only getting 30 when one of the players is commented out, as in the question.)

You don't want all players to share the same hand, so change `Player.Hand` to not be static (i.e. remove the `static` keyword). Then pass your two initialised players' hands (`player1.hand` and `computer.hand`) as parameters into `dealCards`:

```
public Card dealCards(Hand hand, Hand computerHand)
...
```

I think there's some tidying up to do with regard to which classes have responsibility for doing what (maybe post to codereview.stackexchange.com once you've got the game working), but this change should get you up and running.

Comment: Thanks for that, it's a step forward, but it complains that it cannot convert the player class to a hand class. Only way around it is if I pass player1.hand into the dealcards method.

Comment: Sorry, my bad. I've fixed the answer to match: passing the hand in directly should be fine. You might also want to think about whether `dealCards` (why the lower-case D?) should be part of `Deck` at all (it's not the deck doing the dealing) -- maybe it belongs in a separate `Game` class? It's probably a good idea to make all your fields (`Player.hand`, `Hand.cardsInHand`) private and then add only the public methods that are needed to access them (like you have with `Deck.deckOfCards`). But it looks like you're well on the way. Maybe I'll get to play your game when it's finished :-)

Comment: See above for how I solved it (at this point - Whether it'll work as I go along, I'm not to sure. All I know is that each hand had equal cards

Comment: Looks like you've also changed `dealCards()` to remove one card from the deck and return it. But my approach would have worked just as well.

Comment: I'll probably go back and use your method when my mind can follow it clearly. Sometimes you have to go with what works at the moment :)